# SSRS Syntax - Countdistinct ([column A] where [column B] = X)

Tags: reporting-services

I have a dataset that looks like the picture below. I need to do a number of things with it in SSRS but I'm having an issue with the fact that some references (phone calls) have multiple outcomes but should only be counted once. I'm not sure how to put conditions into a distinct count.

What I need is

- A count of distinct reference numbers where the type is "normal operator call" (22 in the attached picture)
- The average connected duration of distinct reference numbers (261.14)
- The number of distinct references where the start time was between 08:30 and 17:00 **and** the type was "normal operator call" (19)

I know that you can use countdistinct in SSRS but I'm not sure what the correct syntax for a count distinct **with** a condition is. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

[image]

Edit : Added SQL Query by request

```
SELECT

[reference]

,dateadd(hh,1,[Start Time]) AS [Call Time]
,[type]
,[ring (ms)]/1000 AS [Ring Time]
,[connected (ms)]/1000 AS [connected]

,rtrim([rhoutcome]) AS [Outcome]

From 
[InboundCallsView] AS ICV  
LEFT JOIN ianalyse.[dbo].[iAnalyse3_iResultsHeaderXML] IRES 
ON  ICV.[Activation ID]  = IRES.[rhActivationId] 
AND ires.[rhAccountNo] = '310169'
 AND ([rhstarttime] BETWEEN '2017-06-13' AND '2017-06-14' OR [rhStartTime]    IS null)

WHERE [account] = '310169'

AND dateadd(hh,1,[Start Time]) BETWEEN '2017-06-13' AND '2017-06-14'

AND [type] <> 'Call diverted'
```

Comment: How is this data getting into your report?  Can you not just add a dataset that drops out your desired output, as these aggregations will be a lot faster on the server rather than in your report.

Comment: Can you edit the dataset, this might be easier to do in SQL

Comment: The end user wants the raw data as well as the calculations. I guess I could write two queries one that brings back the data and one that does the aggregation?

Comment: You could get the dataset as it appears above along with the aggregations in a single query. If you post what you want the results to look like exactly and, if possible, the rawdata in a usable format (t-SQL statement, csv etc) then it won;t take long to put a query together.

Answer (score 0):

That's tricky in SSRS in my opinion.  I would try to do it in SQL and not knowing what tables go to which columns the best I could is below.  Calc1, Calc2, and Calc3 columns would always be the same so you can just plug them into the footer row with MAX as the aggregate.

```
create table #final 
(
    reference varchar(50),
    [Call Time] datetime,
    [type] nvarchar(500),
    [Ring Time] int,
    [connected] int,
    [Outcome] nvarchar(500),
    Calc1 int,
    Calc2 int,
    Calc3 int
)

--put current query into temp table:
insert into #final
(
    reference ,
    [Call Time] ,
    [type] ,
    [Ring Time] ,
    [connected] ,
    [Outcome]
)
SELECT
    [reference]
    ,dateadd(hh,1,[Start Time]) AS [Call Time]
    ,[type]
    ,[ring (ms)]/1000 AS [Ring Time]
    ,[connected (ms)]/1000 AS [connected]
    ,rtrim([rhoutcome]) AS [Outcome] 
From [InboundCallsView] AS ICV  
LEFT JOIN ianalyse.[dbo].[iAnalyse3_iResultsHeaderXML] IRES 
ON  ICV.[Activation ID]  = IRES.[rhActivationId] 
    AND ires.[rhAccountNo] = '310169'
    AND ([rhstarttime] BETWEEN '2017-06-13' AND '2017-06-14' OR [rhStartTime]    IS null)
WHERE [account] = '310169'
AND dateadd(hh,1,[Start Time]) BETWEEN '2017-06-13' AND '2017-06-14'
AND [type] <> 'Call diverted'

-----Get the calculations:
--calc1
update f
set Calc1 = b.Calc1
from #final f
inner join 
    (select
            count(Distinct reference) as Calc1
     from #final f
     where [type] = 'normal operator call'
     ) as b
     on 1=1

--calc2
update f
set Calc2 = b.Calc2
from #final f
inner join 
    (

    select --get the average per distinct reference
        avg(connectedDistinct) as Calc2
    from 
            (--distinct reference by max Connected
            select
                 reference,
                 max([connected]) as connectedDistinct
             from #final f 
             group by 
                reference
             ) as b2
    ) as b
     on 1=1

--calc3
update f
set Calc3 = b.Calc3
from #final f
inner join 
    (  
            select
                count(Distinct reference) as Calc3
            from #final f 
            where
              convert(time, [Call Time]) >= '08:30:00.0000000'
               and convert(time, [Call Time]) <= '17:00:00.0000000'
    ) as b
     on 1=1


select
    reference ,
    [Call Time] ,
    [type] ,
    [Ring Time] ,
    [connected] ,
    [Outcome] ,
    Calc1 ,
    Calc2 ,
    Calc3 
from #final
order by
    [Call Time]
```